# Unit tests print exception after upgrading liquibase to 3.2.2

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I have a spring boot/liquibase app and after upgrading liquibase to 3.2.2 unit tests starts to print this exception, but tests still pass:

```
[WARN] liquibase - Error initializing SpringLiquibase
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:156) ~[spring-web-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.init(SpringLiquibase.java:74) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.resource.AbstractResourceAccessor.(AbstractResourceAccessor.java:19) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.(SpringLiquibase.java:64) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.createResourceOpener(SpringLiquibase.java:388) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.createLiquibase(SpringLiquibase.java:349) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:300) [liquibase-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613) [spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550) [spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot doesn't support Liquibase 3.2.2 at the moment. I haven't seen the exact error that you've posted in the question, but I suspect it's another symptom of the incompatibilities between Liquibase 3.0.x and 3.2.x.

To be safe, you should stick with Liquibase 3.0.x for now, although I believe that 3.1.x may work as well.

There's an open [Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1382) describing some of the problems with 3.2.x. There's also an open [Spring Boot pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/1743) that provides compatibility with Liquibase 3.2.x. It's scheduled for inclusion in Spring Boot 1.2 which is due for release in Novemeber.